# Java Stream reduce() to conditionally insert or update the items in resulting Collection

Tags: java-stream, java-17

How to apply reduce to add in collection as well as manipulate or drop the inserting objects.

For example,
I've a `List<Info>` where each `Info` object contain only one entry in `orderIds` List.
from this List I want to create a `Set<Info>` or `List<Info>`.
in the final collection, If `catagory` of 2 `Info` is same then instead of adding `Info` object as a new Entry in Collection, I just append in `orderIds` &  Sum up the price.

Here is more explanation by code

```java
class Info {
    String category;
    List<Integer> orderIds;
    int price;

    public Info(String category, List<Integer> orderIds, int price) {
        this.category = category;
        this.orderIds = orderIds;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

For example if list is made as following.

```java
private static List<Info> getInfos() {
    List<Info> infos = new ArrayList<>();

    infos.add(new Info("CATAGORY_1", Collections.singletonList(110), 200));
    infos.add(new Info("CATAGORY_1", Collections.singletonList(120), 300));
    infos.add(new Info("CATAGORY_2", Collections.singletonList(210), 1000));
    infos.add(new Info("CATAGORY_2", Collections.singletonList(220), 2000));
    infos.add(new Info("CATAGORY_3", Collections.singletonList(300), 400));
    return infos;
}
```

For above dataset, The final Collection (Set or List) is expected to contain contain only following 3 entries

```
Info("CATAGORY_1", List(110,120), 500);
Info("CATAGORY_2", List(210,220), 3000);
Info("CATAGORY_3", List(300), 400);
```

The Idea is to have an `accumulator` to add in collection and `merge` (based upon `category`) to update one of the Info.
I'm unable to figure out how to achieve it with reduce.

```java
getInfos().stream()
     .reduce(new HashSet<Info>(), ?? , ?? );
```

Comment: There are multiple compilation errors.  `Collections.singletonList(110)` creates a `List<Integer>`, but the constructor accepts `List<Long>. Then the `price` field defined as `String` but only integers were passed. I've fixed other errors, but it seems it is not a reproductible example.

Comment: The snippet were just to depict the idea, not the actual code....Nevertheless, I updated the sample code in question now.... Again `expected result` is just  depiction of what is required, not a test case

Answer (score -1):

Before I show solutions I'd like to point out that `Collections.singletonList()` is an immutable list containing only the specified object. If you would add an element to this the implementation throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`

The modified `Info` class:

**NOTE:** Previous revisions weren't type safe, so I guessed the right types of the fields.

```java
public class Info {
    String category;
    List<Long> orderIds;
    Double price;

    Info(String category, List<Long> orderIds, Double price) {
        this.category = category;
        this.orderIds = new ArrayList<>(orderIds);
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Info{" +
                "category='" + category + '\'' +
                ", orderIds=" + orderIds +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

It also have some potential bugs (e.g. missing null check) I'll fix it later.

The input

```java
var infos = List.of(
        new Info("CATAGORY_1", singletonList(110L), 200d),
        new Info("CATAGORY_1", singletonList(120L), 300d),
        new Info("CATAGORY_2", singletonList(210L), 1000d),
        new Info("CATAGORY_2", singletonList(220L), 2000d),
        new Info("CATAGORY_3", singletonList(300L), 400d)
);
```

What is the desired output?

1. Only one `Info` should belong to each `category`
2. Every `Info` object sould contain all `orderIds` for given category
3. The `price` field should contain summarized value the related `Info` objects.

### Basic solution

At first, that list must split up by `category`.

```java
var tmp = infos.stream().collect(groupingBy(i -> i.category));
```

This creates a `Map<Stirng, List<Info>>` where the key is the category and the value is the list of `Info` objects that belongs to that `category`.

Now, each value has to be flattened to a single `Info` object which contains the merged list of `orderIds` and the summarized price value.

Fortunately `java.util.stream.Collectors` has a lot of useful method to achieve that.

The `groupingBy` method has an other signature which accepts a downstream collector.

```java
 Collector<T, ?, Map<K, D>> groupingBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier,
                                       Collector<? super T, A, D> downstream)
```

> Returns a Collector implementing a cascaded "group by" operation ..., and then performing a reduction operation on the values associated with a given key using the specified downstream Collector.

But we have to collect **and transform** those elements, so we have to use an other collector too.

```java
Collector<T,A,RR> collectingAndThen(Collector<T,A,R> downstream, Function<R,RR> finisher)
```

> Adapts a collector which performs the action of the downstream collector, followed by an additional finishing step.

```java
var result = infos.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
                i -> i.category, // group by category
                collectingAndThen(toList(), sub -> sub.stream()
                        // skip the first element, because it is set as identity to reduce
                        .skip(1) 
                        // first element set as identity
                        .reduce(sub.get(0), (id, info) -> {
                            id.orderIds.addAll(info.orderIds);
                            id.price += info.price;
                            return id;
                        }, (a, b) -> a))) // dummy combiner only for sequential streams

        ) // here we have a Map<String, Info> where Info is cumulated
        .values(); // the values of this map is a Collection<Info>
```

### Better solution

Because the question was tagged with `java-17` I prefer `record` structure. And together with that I made some improvement on the code (e.g. null checks or double brackets collection initialization).

```java
public record InfoRecord(String category, List<Long> orderIds, Double price) {

    public InfoRecord(String category, List<Long> orderIds, Double price) {
        this.category = Optional.of(category).get(); // category is mandatory
        this.orderIds = Optional.ofNullable(orderIds)
                .orElseGet(ArrayList::new); // orderIds are optional just in case
        this.price = Optional.of(price).get(); // price is mandatory
    }
}
```

```java
public class AccumulatorService {

    private static final BinaryOperator<InfoRecord> merge = (r0, r1) -> new InfoRecord(r0.category(),
            new ArrayList<>() {{ // using double brakcets initialization to concatenate two collections
                addAll(r0.orderIds());
                addAll(r1.orderIds());
            }},
            Double.sum(r0.price(), r1.price()) // better way to summarize two doubles
    );

    public Collection<InfoRecord> cumulate(List<InfoRecord> infos) {
        return infos.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(
                        InfoRecord::category,  // now, method reference is available
                        collectingAndThen(toList(), sub -> sub.stream().skip(1)
                                // Using BinaryOperator (merge) instead of inline lambda and
                                // use merge also as combiner to handle parallel streams
                                .reduce(sub.get(0), merge, merge)))

                ).values();
    }
}
```

Now, it works:

```java
final var service = new AccumulatorService();
final var infos = List.of(
        new InfoRecord("CATAGORY_1", singletonList(110L), 200d),
        new InfoRecord("CATAGORY_1", singletonList(120L), 300d),
        new InfoRecord("CATAGORY_2", singletonList(210L), 1000d),
        new InfoRecord("CATAGORY_2", singletonList(220L), 2000d),
        new InfoRecord("CATAGORY_3", singletonList(300L), 400d)
);
var result = service.cumulate(infos);
```

### Using one reducer and `HashMap.merge()`

From javadoc of merge method:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function, or removes if the result is null.

Now, `groupingBy` function and reducing multiple streams are no longer necessary.

The modified service:

```java
public class AccumulatorService {

    private static final BinaryOperator<InfoRecord> merge = (r0, r1) -> new InfoRecord(r0.category(),
            new ArrayList<>() {{ // using double brakcets initialization to concatenate two collections
                addAll(r0.orderIds());
                addAll(r1.orderIds());
            }},
            Double.sum(r0.price(), r1.price()) // better way to summarize two doubles
    );

    public Collection<InfoRecord> cumulate(List<InfoRecord> infos) {
        return infos.stream()
                .reduce(new HashMap<String, InfoRecord>(), (map, elem) -> {
                    map.merge(elem.category(), elem, merge);
                    return map;
                }, (m0, m1) -> m0)
                .values();
    }
}
```